# How to invert the filling of the recycleview using FlexboxLayou?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-flexboxlayout

I'm using FlexboxLayou in my project, but I can't reverse the data taken from the firebase, I want it in decreasing order. I tested:

```
Collections.reverse (list);
```

it works, not using FlexboxLayou, but as my project has different layouts the best option to flex the layouts was using the FlexboxLayou. I tried on the recycleview to change:

```
app: stackFromEnd = "true"
app: reverseLayout = "true"
```

It didn't have any effect.
 I changed the parameters in FlexboxLayou, but some give an error.

```
FlexboxLayoutManager flexboxLayoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(context);
        flexboxLayoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
        flexboxLayoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.CENTER);
        flexboxLayoutManager.setAlignItems(AlignItems.STRETCH);
        flexboxLayoutManager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);
```

If I change FlexWrap.WRAP to FlexWrap.WRAP_REVERSE the adapter also fails.

Error after using Collections.reverse (list):

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pup, PID: 28144
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.pup.Viewholder.Prop.ViewPropU cannot be cast to com.example.pup.Viewholder.Prop.ViewPropS
        at com.example.puplica.Adaptadores.AdapatadorProp.onBindViewHolder(AdapatadorProp.java:92)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayoutManager.getFlexItemAt(FlexboxLayoutManager.java:456)
        at com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayoutManager.getReorderedFlexItemAt(FlexboxLayoutManager.java:474)
        at com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxHelper.calculateFlexLines(FlexboxHelper.java:429)
        at com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxHelper.calculateHorizontalFlexLines(FlexboxHelper.java:249)
        at com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayoutManager.updateFlexLines(FlexboxLayoutManager.java:953)
        at com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(FlexboxLayoutManager.java:729)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18010)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5911)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18010)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5911)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18010)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5911)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18010)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5911)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18010)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5911)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18010)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5911)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3175)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18010)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5911)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2776)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2477)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1544)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7602)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(
```

Give error on the adapter.
I did a great research and I couldn't get a result, I tried to invert the content received by firebase, but the subject is very complex, and I couldn't do it. there must be a simple way to do this.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?